# detecting FireFox4 browser

Tags: firefox, browser, detect, firefox4

How to detect FireFox4 or any updated versions of FireFox, to include specific stylesheet?
Note: FF4 and FF5 gives font-size too small when printed. on screen its fine(FF3.0 to FF5).

Comment: @Eamorr How's that going to help when *printing* the page?

Comment: @Nisha: It might be better to fix the problem at its source instead of curing the symptoms. If I try to print this page in Firefox 5 or Firefox 3.6 (both set to "Shrink to fit") the font size is absolutely identical. Maybe the size setting is different in your Firefox 4/5 profile, to change it click the Firefox button, there Print and Page Setup - "Scale" setting is the one you are interested in. Or there is something special about your page, try to find out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inspect the user agent string.  How you do that wil depend on what technique you wish to use and what platform you are on.  In PHP you can inspect the value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`, or you can do it using jQuery as Eamorr says.  It is also possible a number of other ways, you'll have to tell us more about your setup.

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` will not tell you if the page is to be printed or not.

Comment: Of course not, but if he knows the browser he can supply amendments to his print stylesheet accordingly

Comment: i work in windows. can any one tell why does the fireFox 4 and Firefox 5 versions give font size too small when printed? Also any solutions to make the print look better..

Comment: As has already been said, if you detect the environment you can deliver an alternative print stylesheet for the problematic browsers.

Comment: If you detect Firefox by looking at `HTTP_USER_AGENT` please remember to look for `rv: n.n` (Gecko version) and not for the Firefox version. There are more browsers using the Gecko engine, e.g. SeaMonkey - you want to treat them correctly. Gecko 1.9.2 corresponds to Firefox 3.6, Gecko 2.0 to Firefox 4, Gecko 5.0 to Firefox 5 (in future Gecko versions and Firefox versions will be identical).